# While the application is open

Tags: c#

I am trying to implement a card game(similar to bridge). There are bunch of classes which represent Suit,Player,Cart,Team,etc.

In each round each player throws 4 cards and once all 13 cards from each player’s hand are thrown, we can  calculate  points each team of two players collected.

I need to tell the Main form somehow to end (better term is to start a new round ) when all 52 cards are thrown.

I am trying to implement the following pseudo algorithm

```
While(not all cards played) 
{
  continue the game

}
Calculate each player’s score according to the collect hand
```

Not sure where to put this while loop. Certainly not in Form_Load.

Comment: You will not have a while loop. Please take the time to learn the basics of event-driven programming.

Comment: You would normally have *some* kind of interaction with the UI.  You for example don't finish a round until the user has selected a card to play.  So your UI needs to call, say, PlayCard() in a Click event handler and that can return a game status value.  Or you raise an event.

Comment: Hey Sammy, what are you working with here? C# can be used in a lot of ways. Is it WPF? WinForms? Console? Unity? In traditional game development, you often have a game loop that looks like what you wrote here. However, in many of these environments, what you think of as the game loop is handled by the framework. You end up writing code that handles events when they occur. So for example, in WPF and WinForms, a method might automatically fire as soon as a card is moved into a container. There is no need for a game loop in that case. I suggest Pluralsight as a good starting point. Good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is somewhat general, so here is my primary reccommendation:

**Don't put business logic in a view class**. Your view should react via method calls/events to changes in underlying state. Unfortunately, this is much easier in a tech built around an MVVM/MVC pattern (like WPF).

That being said, I would create a "GameController" class that manages the game state and holds rules such as this. Every time a card is played it would run through a method like:

```
void CheckRoundEnd()
{
      if (cardsPlayed == 52)
          EndRound();
}
```

`EndRound` would raise an event that the form listened to, or invoke appropriate methods on the form to reset the view for the next round.